# r nls trace iterations all the same

Tags: r

I am trying to use the nls() function to fit some data, but I keep getting the error "number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50".

To determine if I am just making bad starting guesses, I re-created the problem with "fake data" in the code below. It looks like the initial guesses are not the problem.

I also tried setting `trace = TRUE` and found that all of the iterations are the same, so I doubt increasing the number of iterations will work.

```
# test code ####

set.seed(12345)

calc_exp <- function(a, m, x, b){
  y <- a - exp(m*-x + b)
  return(y)
}

a_i <- 583
m_i <- 0.0025
b_i <- 3.8

noise <- 2*rnorm(800)

xs <- 1:800
data <- calc_exp(a_i, xs, m_i, b_i) + noise

plot(xs, data)

ys <- calc_exp(a_i, xs, m_i, b_i)
lines(xs, ys, col = "blue")

fit <- nls(ys~calc_exp(a, m, xs, b), start = c(a = a_i, m = m_i, b = b_i)
       , trace = T)
```

(I don't think I can linearize the function and use `lm()` because there is no log rule for adding and subtracting, and you can't make a linear log-log plot with the data here)

P.S. Thanks for the help -- I'm new to stack overflow